# What's the fastest COVID-19 test available?

Tags: covid-19, sars-cov-2

This video [1 minute COVID-19 test](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxJSMuHG1Fo) talks about a 1 minute COVID-19 testing which isn't available to the public yet. In the market and online, you can find fast COVID-19 tests which deliver the result in 10 minutes. Here in the province I live in we don't have community transmission anymore and we could be living a normal life if fast COVID-19 tests could be done on routes, where infected people from other provinces come to ours bringing the virus again.

Therefore I would like to know, what's the fastest COVID-19 test available nowadays?

Comment: I don't have an answer; the breathalizer that you link is the fastest approach that I have read about. Effective duration of test methods varies also depending on whether they are lab tests, point-of-care tests, or home tests: Even though a test might be really fast in principle, if you need a lab, the logistics and turnaround test will make it slow. Apart from speed, I would like to emphasize that false positive and false negative rates are important criteria for a test. I'd rather wait 30 instead of 10 minutes for a result, if it means the test will miss fewer infections.